# Linux kernel action upon init process exiting

Tags: linux-kernel, init, exit-status

Say I am writing my own init program running on a Linux kernel.

**What happens when my init program exits with return value 0 ?**

Additionally is the behaviour different if the return value is non-zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What happens when my init program exits with return value 0?

This code, from the `find_child_reaper` function in `kernel/exit.c`, is run:

```
panic("Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x%08x\n",
       father->signal->group_exit_code ?: father->exit_code);
```

And consequently this message appears on your console:

> Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000

Comment: Thank you! I misunderstood the message, and was thinking this is the kernel panic you will get if you try to send a kill signal to init, not the action performed if init just returns.

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen There is no such thing as "just returns" for a process. When you return from `main` in a `C` program, you return to a stub function in the `C` library that then invokes a system call to end the process, just as if you called `exit()`.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: Thank you, that broadens my understanding. :)

Comment: Wow! The crap you learn just passing through is amazing.

Comment: If someone is wondering what the `?:` means, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319144. In summary: the syntax `x ?: y` is a nonstandard GCC extension and is equivalent to `x ? x : y`.